# Move geom_smooth() area backwards

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using this line of code to make the plot

```
ggplot(result, aes(1:nrow(result), surv))
        + geom_point(color= "firebrick")
        + geom_smooth(method= loess, level= 0.99, linetype= 0)
```

[image: plot]

Since my points are in the background, the smoother area makes them lose a bit of color when its above them.

How can I move my smooth area to the background so my points don't lose color?

Comment: Try calling `geom_smooth()` before calling `geom_point()`. Also, you can use the `alpha` parameter to make either of these `geom`s lighter or darker.

Comment: Calling geom_smooth() before worked like a charm.

Comment: @nrussell, please add your comment as a answer so the question could be closed.